# Android Studio Emulator Does Not Start App

Tags: java, android, gradle, emulation

The Emulator launches. However when attempting to run an app, the app does not show up on emulator. I get a message that says "Gradle build finished with 1 error(s). How can I rectify this problem?

Comment: What error are you getting in gradle?

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\*ommitted*\.gradle\caches\2.10\classAnalysis\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option

Comment: Tried running --stacktrace. Did not work.     Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'stacktrace' not found in root project 'Test1'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Try this: 
Go to the path `C:\Users*ommitted*\.gradle\caches` and delete the folder `2.10` and restart Android studio.

Comment: Successs!!!!!! Thank you! Do I have to worry about 2.10 folder?

Comment: I think not.. If my solution worked, I will post my comment as answer, so you can accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Go to the path `C:\Users*ommitted*\.gradle\caches` and delete the folder `2.10` and restart Android studio.